# How to align applets on Gnome panel

Tags: ubuntu, gnome

Does anyone know how to align applets on Gnome panel? For example I add notification area and there's five icons (you see it on the left of processor icon). Then, I plug my BlueTooth adapter out of my laptop and it's logo disappears, leaving blank space on the right side of applet.

Here's screenshot:

[image]

Same happens with any applet that's width can change (for example tray). Is there any way to tell applet "Move right as far as you can".

Comment: Are you certain that you want to do this? The empty space conveys information: this thing that was here is not here now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a [feature request in Gnome's bugzilla](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=557925) asking for a way to do this, so it seems it is not possible at the moment. For now, what you can do is arrange all icons which are always visible at the very right of the panel and lock them (Rightclick->Lock to panel). Then the icons which may vanish at least don't interrupt their position.